# Simple Request: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am using a simple JSON Ajax request to get some JSON data. 
But all the time I try to use the JSON object I get the following issue:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#home', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/documents.json",
        dataType: "json",
        type: 'GET',
        async: true,
        success: function(result) {
            //ajax.parseJSON(result);
            $.each(result, function(idx, obj) {
                alert(obj.name);
            });
        },
        error: function(request, error) {
            alert('Network error has occurred please try again!' + ' ' + request + ' ' + error);
        }
    });
});
```

my JSON file is valid and looks like that:

```
{
  "books": [{
    "id": "01",
    "name": "info",
    "dateiname": "info.pdf"
  }, {
    "id": "02",
    "name": "agb",
    "dateiname": "agb.pdf"
  }, {
    "id": "03",
    "name": "raumplan",
    "dateiname": "raumplan.pdf"
  }, {
    "id": "04",
    "name": "sonstiges",
    "dateiname": "sonstiges.pdf"
  }, {
    "id": "05",
    "name": "werbung",
    "dateiname": "werbung.pdf"
  }]
}
```

Comment: is this result when you console.log in success?

Comment: How/Where are you checking `length` of What?

Comment: @Pekka Yes, this is the console output. I am not checking for anything. I just would like to parse the JSON file an add it to a list view

Answer (score 0):

You should perform something like the following:

```
if(result && result["books"]) {
    $.each(result["books"], function(idx, obj) {
        alert(obj.name);
    });
}
```

Comment: `jQuery.each` can loop on an object.

Comment: @Magus Yes, `jQuery.each` can loop on an object, but `result` is not an array.

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery.each` can make this error if you provide a `undefined` value. But `result` can't be undefined or `jQuery` would throw a JSON parse error. At least `result` is an empty object `{}` (or an empty array `[]`).

Your code never read the `length` of anything. So i assume your error is somewhere else in your code.

Double check the error in your console. You should have the exact line of the error. And the stack too.

But there's still an error in your code. You should have this :

```
$.each(result.books, function(idx, obj) {
    alert(obj.name);
});
```